# restringir acessos htaccess

Tags: php, linux, htaccess

eu tenho a seguinte estrutura de pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que qualquer acesso direto externo feito em arquivos dos diretórios helper e uteis, sejam encaminhados para o arquivo index.html que está na raiz do site.

Ou seja, quero que a única página que poderá ser acessada diretamente (por um app em um smartphone) seja:  /v1/index.php.

esse tipo de acesso não quero que aconteça:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E nem esse outro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Espreita nos ficheiros de configuração `/etc/apache2/...conf `   vê se existe (1) `  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` e (2) talvez algo como: `Options +Indexes`  (que estaria a permitir ver as directorias)

Comment: Você está usando wamp ou está rodando no linux? Se for no linux, você pode mudar as permissões da pasta para 700 por exemplo, aí vai aparecer a mensagem "Forbiden". Não sei se da pra fazer no wamp, porque usei poucas vezes.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das opções é reescrever tudo para `v1/index.php`

```
RewriteRule ^ v1/index.php [L]
```

E a outra é banir o acesso:

```
RewriteRule ^(helper|uteis)/ - [F,L]
```